user admin privileges batch file
How can we give admin privileges to a pc user who is a user? I know the admin password.
Is there a batch file without entering the control panel?

Who are "we"? Is this a temporary need, a one-time need, or something more long term or ongoing?

There is a simple command you can run. You can enter it directly in the Command Prompt, or create a batch file.
Do note that you have to enter this from a Command Prompt that was run as Administrator, or run the batch file as administrator, and use the credentials from a user that is already administrator.
The command is as follows:
net localgroup Administrators /add MyUser

replace MyUser with the username of the user you want to make Administrator.
After this change was made, the user has to log out and log in (or restart the computer) for it to become effective.
